# How do i convert variable name to string name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Assume I have the following SQL snippet in SQL Server 2012:

```
DECLARE @fname varchar(20), @strVarName varchar(50)
SET @fname = 'cronus'

SET @strVarName = COVERT_VARIABLE_TO_STRING_NAME ( @fname)

--this should return '@fname'. this is not a value conversion this is converting a variable name to a string name 
SELECT @strVarName
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: @UsamaZafar i want to store variable name and its value in a table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reflection in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974358/reflection-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I think you have another issue you want to solve, to which you think converting a variable name to string is a solution. I'm pretty sure (as in 99.999999999999%) you are looking at the issue the wrong way. You have not told us what your real issue is, just your attempted solution. This is what is referred to as an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974358/reflection-in-sql-server-2008). You may be able to retrieve column or table names from its catalog views but with variables you're out of luck. Maybe you'll find another way to solve this issue with dynamic SQL.

Comment: how would i do this in dynamic SQL

Comment: @Dore.Ad Depends on what do you want to achieve. Maybe you could add a use case to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic sql query

```
DECLARE @fname varchar(20), @sql varchar(MAX)
SET @fname = 'cronus'

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @fname

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are following Character data types used to store character strings:

```
char,
varchar,
nvarchar,
text,
```

If u already used variable as String then why need to convert as a string

```
    DECLARE @fname varchar(20), @strVarName varchar(50)
    SET @fname = 'cronus'

    SET @strVarName =  @fname

    SELECT @strVarName
```

if needed use CAST and CONVERT function

Answer (score 0):

This is such a bizarre question, sounds like something I'd try to do.

Hmm, SQL is not supposed to do this but I guess, it doesn't mean you can't make it.

I think you would effectively have to write your own process to pull this off, something along the lines of:

Create `dbo.sProcInserts` stored procedure to insert values into a table:

- Takes VariableName, Value and possibly table name to insert into as parameters

Create `dbo.sProcExec` stored procedure to execute stored procedure:

- Before execute, read stored procedure into a variable
- Find all variables that are SET (i.e. they have a `SET @Var =` OR `SELECT @Var =`)
- After each variable set, add to your string a line that calls dbo.sProcInserts with the name of the variable and a `select @Variable`
- Execute your newly written stored procedure

That way you don't have to actually make any modifications to your sProcs and it should catch the flow of variables and their changes through your procedure

Answer (score -1):

However the requirement itself is a bit strange for me, but here is a way that could be a good start point for you:

```
declare @var1 int
Set @var1= 1
--some code here
declare @var2 nvarchar(max)
set @var2 = 10
--some other code here
declare @var3 bit

print @@VERSION
print 'this is fake @value inside a string'

--$ This is a Hint to help me find the Query that should parsed
declare @sql varbinary(max)
select @sql=sql_handle 
from sys.sysprocesses
where spid=56

declare @q nvarchar(max)
select @q=  substring(text,1,charindex('$',text)-3) from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sql)

Select distinct rtrim(ltrim(substring(Name,1,charindex(' ',Name)))) as Name from(
    Select substring(replace(Name,'=',' '),8, Len(Name)) as Name from dbo.SplitString(@q,'declare ')
    ) as K
    where Name like '@[^@]%'
```

By running the above query you will get the variables name. 
Output:

```
@var1
@var2
@var3
```

You can find the source code for SplitString function  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/1666800)
Note: If you are using SQL Server 2016 and your database's compatibility level is equal or greater than 130, you can also use `SPLIT_STRING` introduced by Microsoft it self. [Learn more Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)